# Clarify about path lifting and homotopy lifting

Tags: general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology

Studing from the notes provided by our professor, I came across the unique lifting theorem, the path lifting theorem (the lifting of a path is unique if the initial point is fixed) and the homotopy lifting theorem (the lifting $G$ of a homotopy is unique if $G (0,t) $ is fixed). Now, I noticed that these theorem are proved one independently from the other; however, couldn't one treat the last two theorems as corollaries of the unique lifting? A path in a space $X $ is defined as a continuous function from $I=[0,1] $ to $X $, and a homotopy is a continuous function from $I×I $ to  $X$ in our definition; $I $ and $I×I $ are connected, and we are fixing a point in the path theorem, and more than one point in the homotopy theorem. These conditions are sufficient to apply the unique lifting theorem, aren't they? Thank you in advance

> Unique lifting theorem: given a connected space $X $ and a continuous function $f $ from $X $ to a topological space $Y $, consider two liftings of $f $ to a covering $E $ of $Y $. Call these liftings $g $, $h $; then $g (x)=h (x) $ for a point $x\in X $ implies $g\equiv h $.
>
> Path lifting theorem: $X$ is topological space, $E $ is a covering of $X $. Consider a path  $\gamma $ in $X $; then there is a unique lifting of $\gamma $ to $E $, say $\gamma '$, such that $\gamma '(0)=e$ for a fixed point $e\in E $.
>
> Homotopy lifting theorem: $X$ is topological space, $E $ is a covering of $X $. Consider a homotopy $F:I×I \to X $, and call $\gamma $ the path defined by $F (0,t) $; then there is a unique lifting of $F$ to $E $, say $G$, such that $G (0,t)= \gamma '(t)$, where $\gamma '$ is a fixed lifting of $\gamma $.

Comment: What is the unique lifting theorem? In a lecture, which basically copied Hatcher, we proved the homotopy lifting theorem and deduced the path lifting theorem as a corollary, so some ways to make your life easier seem to exist...

Comment: I would also like to know what specifically which theorems you are referring to. I suspect you are right, but I want to make sure I understand you correctly before saying that

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I'm sorry, I made an edit to the post with the theorems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The unique lifting theorem has nothing to do with the *existence* of a lifting. Existence requires a separate proof, and this can be easily done for paths. But in fact the uniqueness of the lifted paths is based on the unique lifting therorem.

The homotopy lifting theorem is closely related to the path lifting theorem. Assume we have a homotopy $H : X \times I \to Y$ and a lifting $f : X \to E$ of $H_0 : X \to Y, H_0(x) = H(x,0)$. Then each $H_x : I \to Y, H_x(t) = H(x,t)$, is a path which has a unique lift to path $H'_x : I \to E$ such that $H'_x(0) = f(x)$. These paths yield a function $H' : X \times I \to E$. However, we need a proof that $H'$ is continuous.

Comment: I know that the uniqueness is not related to the existence, however since $I $ and $I×I $  are both simply connected I thought that the sufficient condition for the lifting (of a continuous function, like a path or a homotopy) was always satisfied. Couldn't one reason like this?

Comment: *sufficient condition for the existence of the lifting

Comment: No, because to prove the existence theorem for lifting maps from simply-connected spaces, one usually uses the unique path-lifting and the homotopy lifting theorems